# how to validate text fields so that it only accepts numbers, python flet

Tags: python, validation, frameworks, textfield, flet

I am trying to validate a text field so that it only accepts numbers when the user writes with the keyboard, but I can't think of how to do it.

example of a text field that I want to be only numeric:

```
self.cedula = TextField(label="Cedula", hint_text="Ingresar Cedula", border_radius=30, border_color="#820000", width=300, height=60)
```

Edit: I found out how to know if the user writes a number or a letter, now my problem is the following

I want everything that is not a number to be eliminated in the else, but I can't find a way, declare the field value to be empty but the entire field is emptied

I attached the function

```
def validarNumeros(self, campo, pagee):
    campo = campo
    pagee = pagee

    digitos = campo.value

    if digitos.isdigit():
        print("numero")
    else:
        print("letra")
        self.cedula.value = ""
        pagee.update()
```

Comment: It should be noted that I am using a framework called flet

Comment: Do you want to validation to happen _as the input is typed_, or when the form is _submitted_?

Comment: I would like it to be as the user writes

Comment: Try adding `keyboard_type= KeyboardType.NUMBER` to the textfield definition.

Comment: I already tried it and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help and I'm starting with Flet. I have taken your function and combined it with the on_change event in such a way that using exceptions does not allow entering anything that is not a number or a single decimal point. Additionally, if something wrong is entered, the numbers already entered and previously validated are not lost. I hope it helps you,

```
import flet
from flet import Page,TextField

last_valid_value = ""

def validate_numbers(field, pagee):
    global last_valid_value
    digits = field.value
    if digits == "":
        last_valid_value = ""
    else:
        try:
            float(digits.replace(",", ""))
            last_valid_value = digits
        except ValueError:
            field.value = last_valid_value
            pagee.update()

def main(page: Page):
    amount = TextField(label="Amount", height=37, on_change=lambda e: validate_numbers(amount, page))
    page.add(amount)

flet.app(target=main)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **input_filter** argument in *flet.TextField*, input_filter take flet.InputFilter that allow you to use a simple regex to filter input. the regex here is "from start, only accept numbers zero or more times". **on_change** event is not called if filter no satisfied:

```
import flet


def main(page: flet.Page):
    def on_text_change(event):
        print(event.data)
    _filter = flet.InputFilter('^[0-9]*')
    textfield = flet.TextField(input_filter=_filter,on_change=on_text_change,autofocus=True)
    page.add(textfield)


flet.app(main)
```

i hope it may help you, sorry for my bad english.